boxplots showing flat line instead of box and whiskers, plotly python
I am attempting to chart a few boxplots, organized by a categorical variable with go.Box. However, when I plot the data, there is just a flat line that shows up. [Note: this question seems well-documented in R, but I have not found a similar question for Python. please link to it if you find one.]
Plotting with px.express does not replicate this error, it seems to be just with go.Box.
MRE for multiple columns:
fares = [random.random() for g in np.arange(10000)]
types = ["new", "new", "old", "old", "really_old"] * 2000

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "bus_fares": fares,
    "bus_types": types
}) 

# -----

traces = []

for k in df["bus_types"].unique():
    trace = go.Box(
        x = [k],
        y = df[df["bus_types"]==k]["bus_fares"],
        marker={"color": next(color_iter)},
        name="bus_types",
        showlegend=False
    )

    traces.append(trace)

go.Figure(traces)

This code renders the plot shown below.

even if we simplify and just plot one box, without the loop, it still shows the same behavior.
#-----
x = "bus_types"
y = "bus_fares"
k = "old"

go.Figure(go.Box(x=[k], y=df[df[x]==k][y].values, name=x, showlegend=False))


Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this behavior in Python?

You are passing x in the for loop as a single value [k].
Replace the x in the loop with
x=df[df["bus_types"] == k]["bus_types"]

This way you will select an array of new,old and so on.
The rest is the same and it will work.
Here Plotly expects arrays with go.Box. Hope this helps.

Got it! that worked. One of those unique facets of plotly [box and whiskers are one dimensional plots].
